# Django: Don't want related manager for two foreign keys to the same model

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get rid of two related managers in a Model because I will never need them. How can I get rid of them?

This is my User Profile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    ...    

    default_upload_container=models.ForeignKey(Container,related_name='idontcare')
    default_query_container=models.ForeignKey(Container,related_name='idontcareneither')
```

Because `default_upload_container` and `default_query_container` are only user specific defaults I guess I will never query them 'backwards'. I still want easy drop down fields in the admin though.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very similar question to [Django: How do i create a foreign key without a related name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345181/django-how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-without-a-related-name)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/ :

> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set
>   related_name to '+' or end it with '+'. For example, this will ensure
>   that the User model won’t have a backwards relation to this model:
>
> user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This was added in django 1.2.

Comment: Since the technology has changed since the first answer was accepted, you might consider selecting this answer.