# Django: How do i create a foreign key without a related name?

Tags: django

I run into the problem of clashing automatic related names, and often having a foreign manager installed on the related model is not needed.

For example, it would be great if i could:

```
class ExtraWidgetThingy(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("product.Product")
    also_tastes_good_with = models.ForeignKey(
        "product.Product", related_name=None)
```

instead of `related_name='extrawidgetthingys_that_also_tastes_good_with_this'`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

> If you'd prefer Django didn't create a backwards relation, set `related_name` to `'+'`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the reference to the docs to. This was mighty helpful!

Comment: Thanks for this answer - any idea why they chose `'+'` to signify this instead of `''` or `None`? Just out of curiosity!

Comment: Choosing `'+'` over `None` must be because it's not a default value. Not setting it passes the default `None`, so would be indistinguishable from not having configured the setting.